# What is a rational elliptic surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, surfaces

I know what is an elliptic surface, and I also know what is a Rational surface. However I can't find the definition of Rational elliptic surface. Can any one help me?

I read this on the Kulikov classification theorem of the central fibre of a semi-stable family of K3 surfaces.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this paper (Heckman+Looijenga)](http://www.math.ru.nl/~heckman/Heck_14.pdf), first paragraph.

Comment: Ok, this is good! thanks for your fast answer. I guess this definition is the same over any field right? (not only over $\mathbb C$).  Based on "A more intrinsic characterization is to say that the surface is rational and admits a relatively minimal elliptic fibration possessing a section."

Comment: @user119176 yes, I don't think the field is really relevant here.

Comment: @IgorRivin: since the answer is one sentence (as per user47686's comment), why not edit your answer to include it?